# Firebase to localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I want to save an object to local storage as a JSON string for offline rendering. Only desire write function at this time for testing. My question is why is only one key/value string (array) writing to localStorage?

### What I've tried

Here is the object I'm trying to save.

```
Addr_states
 -JhMZ6QjAm0FRAcRjivP
 Country: 
 State: 
 -JhMdqTXuayd00hqkp_E
 Country: 
 State: 
 -JhMgVVy_58upfBjf0sO
 Country:  
 State: 
 -JhMjte-ujgsmxgyX8Zf
 Country: 
 State: 
 -JhMkPrScGjvRNVna4Hp
 Country: 
 State: 
 -JhOYj6j4lW4Y38wJDsN
 Country: 
 State:
```

And here's my code so far:

```
function myDataStore (myDataPass)
                    {localStorage.setItem("States", JSON.stringify(myDataPass));}

if (myStorageStatus == true)
{

    if (myOnlineStatus == false)
    {
        myDataSource = "Local Storage";
    }
    else
    {
        myDataSource = "Web Firebase";
        localStorage.removeItem("States");
        var myDataRead = new Firebase('https://myappURL/Addr_states');
        myDataRead.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            myDataGroup = snapshot.val();
            console.log(myDataGroup);
            myDataStore (myDataGroup);
        });


    }
}
```

### Notes

- When pulling cast of the variable `myDataGroup` into the snapshot function, I get the last key/value array as a string without the key (seen in object above) or meta data for last update. Outside the function, the result appears (within the developer console) as an empty object.
- `myDataGroup` was declared at top of the code block, outside the scope of the function.
- Changed to add code suggested from commenter below - produces single string (array) last one in States - this - {"Country":"USA","State":"Utah"}

Comment: how are you going to get the data from Firebase if your offline?     The problem is that the code is async. it won't exist outside the callback closure, you'd need to fire a function inside the callback passing the data as an arg and have a isOffline esq check

Comment: Natedog—I've tried to fix up the grammar and question structure a bit, but I'm not sure exactly what you're saying in your notes. Is it that the value of the `myDataGroup` variable within the callback is `null` (or `{}`) outside of the callback?

Comment: Have not written that function yet. There will be no cold-starts. Application will connect initially online and then update every time page refreshes. When offline app will revert to localStorage 'array'. Will quickly add in future add check against time stamp to update local storage quickly thereafter.

Comment: Jordan - No dev console shows empty string on callback unless setItem is moved within function. The array above is just a copy of the formatting of the the firebase 'table' (nosql) - it has the country as USA and then various states as key/value with USA as index for chained events

Comment: I see code, data and statements/notes. But what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is responding to `child_added` events:

```
var myDataRead = new Firebase('https://myappURL/Addr_states');
myDataRead.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
```

[A `child_added` event fires for every child that is added under the indicated node](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-types). So in your case: a `child_added` event is fired for every state.

That also means that your callback function is invoked for every state. And you then overwrite whatever was in local storage with the information for that state:

```
myDataStore (myDataGroup);
```

So essentially your local storage will now contain whatever the last state was that came from Firebase.

Given that you named your local storage `States`, it seems like you want to store all states in there. This can be most easily accomplished by listening for Firebase's `value` event:

```
var myDataRead = new Firebase('https://myappURL/Addr_states');
myDataRead.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    myDataGroup = snapshot.val();
    console.log(myDataGroup);
    myDataStore (myDataGroup);
});
```

If you also want to loop over the individual states, you can use `forEach`:

```
var myDataRead = new Firebase('https://myappURL/Addr_states');
myDataRead.on('value', function(allStates) {
    allStates.forEach(function(stateSnapshot) {
        console.log(stateSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```